# Variables inside constructor without "self" - Python

Tags: python, oop, constructor, self

I am trying to understand whether declaring variables inside constructors is an ok practice. I only need these variables inside the constructor. I am asking this because most of the times I've seen constructors they only contained self variables. I've tried to find an answer on the internet but had no luck.

Here is an example code

```
class Patient:
    def __init__(self, all_images_path: str):
        all_patient_images = os.listdir(all_images_path)
        all_patient_images = [(all_images_path + x) for x in all_patient_images if 'colourlay' in x]
        self.images: [Image] = [Image.open(img_path) for img_path in all_patient_images]
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code? If yes, what?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design standpoint, `Patient.__init__` is doing too much. I would keep `__init__` as simple as possible:

```
class Patient:
    def __init__(self, images: list[Image]):
        self.images = images
```

The caller of `__init__` is responsible for producing that list of `Image` values. However, that doesn't mean your *user* is the one calling `__init__`. You can define a class method to handle the messy details of extracting images from a path, and calling `__init__`. (Note it gets less messy if you use the `pathlib` module.)

```
from pathlib import Path


class Patient:
    def __init__(self, images: list[Image]):
        self.images = images

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, all_images_path: Path):
        files = all_images_path.glob('*colourlay*')
        return cls([Image.open(f) for f in files])
```

Note that `Image` itself seems to take this approach: you aren't constructing an instance of `Image` directly, but using a class method to extract the image data from a file.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is just a normal function that has a special purpose (initializing the newly created object).

You can do (almost) whatever you like in there. You typically see lines like `self.name = arg` because assignments like these are often required to set up the internal state of the object. It's perfectly fine to have local variables though, and if you find they make your code cleaner, use them.

Comment: This is an important point.  It is a perfectly ordinary function.  It happens to get called automatically when an object is created, and the object instance will be passed as the first parameter (like all class methods), but beyond that it's just a function.